# how to use cx_freeze in linux to create a package to be used in windows

Tags: linux, python-3.x, cx-freeze

how to use cx_freeze in linux to create a one package to be used in windows like .exe or .bin file.
I tested cx_freeze in linux but that make package for linux and in windows is unknown.

for example :

```
$ cxfreeze gui.py
```

and this is file that maked :

```
gui
```

that is running only in linux.

Is there any way to use cx_freeze for making exe or bin package ?

Or any alternative way instead of cx_freeze to make one bin file to execute in other platform independent?

I use python3(3.x).

Comment: I've recently written a tool, [Pynsist](http://pynsist.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which can build Windows installers for Python applications from Linux, with a bit of care.

Answer (score 10):

I've been trying to get cx_freeze properly working on windows in every way possible but with no luck...I was trying to do what you are doing now using Ubuntu but I found this, sadly:
https://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#problems-with-running-frozen-programs

"
Freezing for other platforms

cx_Freeze works on Windows, Mac and Linux, but on each platform it only makes an executable that runs on that platform. So if you want to freeze your program for Windows, freeze it on Windows; if you want to run it on Macs, freeze it on a Mac.

At a pinch, you can try to make a Windows executable using Wine. Our experience is that you need to copy some files in manually after cx_Freeze has run to make the executable work. We don’t recommend this option.
"
I guess the only option is to try doing it with wine?
Have you had any luck?

Comment: is there any reason you can't use Windows directly to generate .exe files with cx_freeze from the scripts?  what kind of problems were you having when you tried it with wine?

Comment: Thanks for support, I use cs_freeze.exe for windows for my wine and with that make gui linux version! No error showed, and with windows my problem is i do not use windows at all!I use Gnu/Linux(Debian).

Comment: that is so strange...
hmm check out what this guy wrote:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.cx-freeze.user/786
"After some fiddling, I've succeeded in getting a tkinter/easygui program to freeze in Python 3.2 & Wine. To do so, I had to copy across the tcl8.5 directory from C:/Python32/tcl/, as well as tcl85.dll and tk85.dll from C:/Python32/DLLs/.

"

Comment: have you given up on this?  We will get it working, don't worry!  :)

Comment: @LuckyLuc - hi, I'm the one who wrote that e-mail. I think I traced the problem to [this unimplemented function](http://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/blob/HEAD:/dlls/imagehlp/modify.c#l44) in WINE. Implementing that might make it possible to freeze in WINE, but I guess it's non-trivial.

Comment: So, cx_freeze CANNOT build cross-platform executables, it will only build executable under the current platform

Answer (score 2):

Did you saw this? Maybe this is making you trouble: "Python on Windows requires the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package. Python 2.6-3.2 uses the 2008 version, **and because of how this is installed, cx_Freeze doesn’t automatically copy it for your application**."

http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-package

Anyway, using this tool (cx_freeze) is so complicated and inefficient that it is probably more easy to write a whole program than to convert it properly to windows executable. I really hope that someone in future will write a more concise and simple convert tool for Python 3.

Comment: Building executables from Python code is a non-trivial job, but any help to make cx_Freeze easier to use or more efficient is welcome. You may also be interested in my [NSIS installer template for a Python application](https://github.com/takluyver/py-nsis-template) - it doesn't build an exe for the application, but it makes an installer which includes Python, so you can distribute your projects to people running on Windows.

Comment: I'm currently in process of learning how to program, so I don't think I can be of any significant help right now ;)

Comment: No worries - feel free to come and help us when you feel better practiced. :)

Answer (score -1):

cx_freeze should work cross-platform as stated in the site :

> cx_Freeze is cross platform and should work on any platform that Python itself works on

*(I haven't tried in linux though)* but you can find a easy explanation over [here](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: "cx_Freeze works on Windows, Mac and Linux, but on each platform it only makes an executable that runs on that platform" , i want any alternate way to make exe file in linux for other platform.

Comment: sorry I didn't properly understand the question, so here you go, this should help you http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: Thanks, but Pyinstaller not support py3 ! only py2.x.

Comment: finding an alternative can't be that hard

Comment: I tested all possible alternative and can not success with anyone.all like cx_freeze,pyinstaller,py2exe,freeze, ...

Comment: Unfortunately cx_freeze developers either lie or they don't know English, cause cx_freeze does NOT build cross-platform executables, but executable under the running platform

Comment: Also, pyinstaller has the exact same limitations as cxfreeze: you cannot generate a Windows exe from Linux.