# cx-freeze can't create .exe file

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I have wrote a simple Python script for searching files & finding the duplicates as I am currently learning Python. Nothing complicated at all. This is also my first try of using cx-freeze to build an Windows executable. I'm using Python 3.3.

I'm using the included cxfreeze script to create .exe file. So, I've typed `cxfreeze search.py --target-dir dist` . Everything goes OK during buildup, and I get the 'dist' folder with files in my home directory (using Lubuntu Linux). Problem is, the Lubuntu recognises the file with the name 'search' as executable, but it hasn't got an .exe extension. On the Windows platform, it is showed just as an file without an extension. So when I try to run it on Windows XP, it just won't work. Adding an .exe extension also do not help.

Do someone have a clue what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use cx\_freeze in linux to create a package to be used in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276543/how-to-use-cx-freeze-in-linux-to-create-a-package-to-be-used-in-windows)

Comment: To make a Windows executable, you have to freeze it on Windows. Freezing on Linux gets you a Linux executable.

Comment: This one seems not to work even on Linux.

Comment: You can make a script executable on Linux easily with adding one line of "shebang" code... i do not understand why would someone need to use this tool to make a Linux executable?

Comment: It's not primarily for Linux, but it can still be useful if your script uses libraries that may not be on the target computer - it can bundle up those libraries to be shipped along with your script. Or if you want to use a newer version of Python than the target machine has.

Comment: Away from basics there is a lot missing on minimal installations.  Also it's useful if you don't want to show them the source code without a struggle.  A useful feature in closed source apps (not that's what we want on Linux but still)